# C How do I compare 2 int

Tags: c, if-statement, integer, addition

I wanna make a captcha like check but all it does is crash.
What's wrong with the code?
My code looks like this:

```
printf("I need to make some tests to ensure that you are a human being.\n");
printf("Let's start\n");

int randomNumber1 = rand() % 100;
int randomNumber2 = rand() % 100;
printf("What is %d + %d ?\n", randomNumber1, randomNumber2);
int randomNumberSum = randomNumber1 + randomNumber2;
int solution;
printf("%d \n", randomNumberSum);
scanf("%d", solution);

if (solution = randomNumberSum) {
    printf("Good job human !\n");

} else {
printf("Nice try, bot \n");
}
```

Comment: Compiler warnings are not just to show progress. Enable and pay heed to them! Note that you should enable and resolve warnings before asking.

Comment: Even better, don't use `scanf` for user input.

Comment: @melpomene: What would you suggest instead?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `fgets` for the actual input, then `sscanf` or `atoi` or `strtol` as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `scanf()` to read an integer, you need to supply the address of the `int` variable:

```
scanf("%d", &solution);
```

You additionally need to use `==` (comparison) rather than `=` (assignment) in your `if`-statement.

Comment: If I put "&" before solution it works perfect. Why is that so?

Comment: @DavisR5 Because `scanf()` needs to know where to put the number. `solution` by itself is just an uninitialized integer, but `&solution` is a an address where the value of that integer is stored.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` expects a pointer to a place to put the information it's reading.

You're giving it the *value* `solution` which, even if it weren't uninitialised (and thus is an indeterminate value) would be vanishingly unlikely to contain the valid address of an object.

You meant to give it `&solution`, which is the address of `solution`.

Also, by the way, you wrote `=` instead of `==`. **Turn on your compiler warnings.**

Answer (score 0):

`if (solution = randomNumberSum)`  is assignment, you are assigning the value of **randomNumberSum** to the variable **solution**, what you mean is actually to check if both are holding the same value...

you need to do `if (solution == randomNumberSum) {`

and you have to do

```
scanf("%d", &solution);
```

(you need to pass as parameter the address of the  variable solution)

instead of `scanf("%d", solution);`

Comment: "shall"/"have to", not "should" - it is no recommendation! And you lack an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problems:

1. You're assigning rather than comparing (my `(solution == randomNumberSum)` vs your `(solution = randomNumberSum)` - this causes the output to be always true
2. You provide an *integer* value to scanf instead of a *pointer to integer*.

See corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("I need to make some tests to ensure that you are a human being.\n");
    printf("Let's start\n");

    int randomNumber1 = rand() % 100;
    int randomNumber2 = rand() % 100;
    printf("What is %d + %d ?\n", randomNumber1, randomNumber2);
    int randomNumberSum = randomNumber1 + randomNumber2;
    int solution;
    printf("%d \n", randomNumberSum);
    scanf("%d", &solution);

    if (solution == randomNumberSum) {
        printf("Good job human !\n");

    } else {
        printf("Nice try, bot \n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why people do that... It's very common for C questions. I just don't fuss about it anymore